# array called from main

Tags: java, arrays, call

I have the following code and I want to call the printArray in the main method so it can print. I keep getting the following errors:

> cannot find symbol
>             `int[] arrays = new int[randomNumbers];`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many random ints?");
    int randomNumbers = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What is the lower bound?");
    int lower = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What is the upper bound?");
    int upper = input.nextInt();

    int range = (upper - lower) + 1;
    printArray(); //not working
}

public static void printArray(int[] array) {
    int[] arrays = new int[randomNumbers];

    for (int t = 0; t < array.length; t++) {
        System.out.print("arr[" + t + "] :" + array[t]);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You declare `randomNumbers` in `main`, so it's not visible to `printArray`

Comment: PrintArray is expecting an argument of type int[], and it is not being given one. arrays is also never filled, just created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, comment out your first declaration in `printArray()`

```
public static void printArray(int[] array) {
  // int[] arrays = new int[randomNumbers];
  for (int t = 0; t < array.length; t++) {
    System.out.print("arr[" + t + "] :" + array[t]);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

But, you should probably use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29),

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Also, in `main()` you need to pass an `int[]` to printArray(),

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] array = new int[randomNumbers];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = lower + rand.nextInt(range);
}
printArray(array);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! It made things a little bit more clear to me.